# How to keep useless zeros in SIUNITX

Tags: siunitx

I want to keep all useless zeros using `siunitx`. How could I ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\verb+\num{5}+: \num{5}\\
\verb+\num{05.0}+: \num{05.0}\\
\verb+\num{0.5}+: \num{0.5}\\
\verb+\num{00.50}+: \num{00.50}\\

\end{document}
```

With the package `xstring` one can use :

```
\newcommand{\Num}[1]{%
    \StrPosition{#1}{.}[\p]%
    \num[minimum-integer-digits=\p-1]{#1}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the options `minimum-integer-digits`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \noindent\verb+\num{5}+: \num{5}\\
  \verb+\num{05.0}+: \num[minimum-integer-digits=2]{5.0}\\
  \verb+\num{0.5}+: \num{.5}\\
  \verb+\num{00.50}+: \num[minimum-integer-digits=2]{.50}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use `\num[parse-numbers=false]{00.50}` or `\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}`. But then the argument of `\num` will not be parsed at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

{\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}%
  \noindent\verb+\num{5}+: \num{5}\\
  \verb+\num{05.0}+: \num{05.0}\\
  \verb+\num{0.5}+: \num{0.5}\\
  \verb+\num{00.50}+: \num{00.50}%
}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: @egreg Of course you are right. I have changed my answer.

Comment: You only really need `minimum-integer-digits` here: the rounding stuff can happily be omitted.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for the note. I have edited my answer again.